# Android ripple on CardView not triggering onClick

Tags: android, onclick, listener, android-cardview, ripple

I want to display a ripple effect on my cardview and know it can be done like this:

```
  android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
```

The problem is, my onclicklistener does not recognise the clicks on my card anymore. Without those two attributes it works fine. I also noticed if I remove the clickable attribute only the first card in my list gets the ripple effect and it starts from the middle, not from where I press. The other cards just get a darker background on click. IS there any fix avaliable for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

For mine I only had

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

not

```
android:clickable="true"
```

and it worked fine with onclicklistener, from where the user clicked.

Comment: On Android 5 I noticed only the first Card in a List displays the ripple effect and it does not start from where the finger touches. The other cards only display a darker background when I press

Comment: Are you using the RecyclerView??

Comment: No, just a simple listView